# Can not get the phpmyadmin to use signin form when connecting to a remote server

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

I set up a Django server ( call it D-server) with Python and Mariadb on Debian. All are working. I wanted to use another server ( call it P-server) that has PHPMyAdmin to manage the D-server MariaDB. I was able to configure remote access, open the firewall and from the P-server log into the D-server and insert data into the table on the D-server via terminal (SSH putty in MariaDB). Then I added the below code to PHPMyAdmin  config.inc.php file to use PHPMyAdmin.

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '192.168.100.11';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = ‘myusername’;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'mypassword';
```

Bingo everything works, I get the pulldown selection and connect to my Server-D using phpMyAdmin on server-P.

However ( the problem), it automatically connects without giving me the ability to use the PHPMyAdmin form sign-in form. so I took out my user name and password with two single quotes:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = ‘’;( that is two Single ‘’)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = ''; ( that is two Single ‘=)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

*I  cannot connect invalid settings:
"phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."*

Then if I use two double “” I get:

*"mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'dbadmin@192.168.100.3'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"*

The question is how to use the phpMyAdmin username and password sign-in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [auth_type](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_auth_type).

Change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
to
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';
```

This will allow users to login with a web-form.

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie'; solved my problem Thanks.